# Is there a function to get the current node that an AGV is in?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm modeling DES using material handling library that has multiple AGVs on guided path. There are a few rectangular nodes that covers some part of the path that AGV travel pass through. I have an event in the AGV that will trigger randomly. Once the event trigger, the action depends on which rectangular node the AGV is currently.

**Question:** Is there a Java function to get the name of the node that the AGV is currently in?

I have similar action to check the path that was set at 'On enter path' in transporterFleet box

```
if(path == path1) {
  action 1}
if(path == path2) {
  action 2}
if(path == path3) {
  action 3}
else {
  action 4}
```

but this time I need to get node name in 'action' within an event. Not sure what function there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the other way around:whenever an AGV enters a node, the node tells the AGV "store me":

1. add a variable of type `Node` named `myNode` into your AGV agent type
2. ensure your node has "access restrictions" enabled, butfeel free to set the capacity to infinity
3. in the on-enter code of the node, write `agent.myNode = self;`

Now, your AGVs will always "know" about their current node. On exit, you could reset it to `null` to avoid confusions